# When connecting my NAS to a switching hub port why doesn't the LNK led light up?

Tags: networking, router, nas, switch

I have two NAS devices. One LinkSys an one Netgear. When connecting either of them (via Category-5 LAN cable) to a 10/100M switching hub port, the LNK lamp for that port does not light up? If I connect a normal PC to the same port (with the same cable) the LNK lamp lights up and that PC can be seen on the network.

NOTE: If I connect wither of my NAS devices to the ports on the router the LNK lamps light up and they can be seen on my network.

Why does this happen? Is it due to different standards? My switching hub came out about 10 years before home NAS devices were available or affordable.

Comment: Also I tried both fixed IP address and DHCP to set the NAS IP address.

Comment: Just how old _is_ your "switching hub"? The fact alone that you call it a 'hub' makes me worry.

Comment: It is a switching hub. I doubt that you can read Japanese but here it is: http://www.planex.co.jp/product/hub/fx05p.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a cross over cable. Normally the hubs(old switches too) aren't capable of make the auto switching like common switches

Check this URL [DTE and DCE](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/cabling-cisco-devices-guide.html)

Comment: You must paraphrase the relevant information in the link in order to prevent link rot and your answer removed. Thank you.